# Disabling custom error pages in Azure Web Apps

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

With a traditional bare metal .NET web application you can set CustomErrors to the RemoteOnly mode, where users will see a friendly custom error page, but admins can remote into the same network as the server, and they will see the raw error page, which includes stack trace etc.  This is often very handy.  With an Azure web app deployment, there is no machine to remote into.  Is there some trick where you can be viewed as non remote by Azure? Or some way to change that custom error setting temporarily?

Comment: if your intend is to see errors. will "diagnostics logging" solve your issue? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Comment: We have access to diagnostics logging, both there and our own internal logging systems, but it can sometimes be hard to tie a log entry to a specific  use case scenario. With the no-custom error page you can replicate what a user is reporting and see the error right there on the page.  It is not essential but we would like to be able to have that option.

Comment: This is probably the best walkthrough of custom error pages I've ever read (no I didn't write it :)) http://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you two options:

**The first option:** You can set the customErrors tag to "Off" value temporarily in your Azure Website editing the web.config file remotely on Visual Studio with the following steps:

- Go to Server Explorer -> Azure and find the Files of your website:

[image]

Double click to the web.config file, edit it and press save.

[image]

Now you should see the error page. **Remember to change again the value for customErrors tag!**

**The second option:** Enable site diagnostics in the configuration section of your Azure Website:

[image]

Then you could find an XML log file in your Azure Website with the error messages:

[image]

I hope this can help you. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware you can, outside of logging to a file.
However, I've always used ELMAH to get my errors, less hassle and more features:

https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC

ala

```
Install-Package Elmah.MVC
```

You can configure security to see the errors remotely.